# How do parentheses change the result of a regular expression match?

Tags: regex, perl

Could anyone explain to be the difference between the following two syntax:

```
($x) = $a =~ /(\d+)/;

$y = $a =~ /(\d+)/;
```

In the example, if `$a`=`100lkj` then
`$x = 100` but `$y = 1`.

With this code I am trying to extract the numerical value present in `$a` string.

I don't exactly understand why?

Answer (score 6):

When you write a Variable inside parenthesis, it forces list context. Which means, that the stuff you want to assign to that variable will be interpreted as a list as well.

In your case, you have a normal match. The return value of a match is a list, containing all matches. If you force a list onto scalar context, the number of entries inside this list is returned. So you have 1 match, which means that this list contains 1 match.

Its not very recommended to use the return value of a regular expression.

You could use the variables `$1, $2, $3,...` for the matches ( matches from parenthesis ).

In your case:

```
$a =~ /(\d+)/;
$x = $1;
```

BTW: `$a` and `$b` are special Variables for `sort`. Please dont use them :).

```
($x) = $a =~ /(\d+)/;
# $x is the first element of the RegEx return value
# ($x, $y, $z) = $a =~ /(\d)(\d)(\d)/;
# $x = first match, $y = second and so on.
```

Comment: Why is it not very recommend to use the return value of a regular expression?

Comment: There is no array context. See http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl

Comment: Yeah. You're right. i just realized [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#/PATTERN/msixpodualgc)

Comment: `Searches a string for a pattern match, and in scalar context returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails.`

Comment: Re "Its not very recommended to use the return value of a regular expression."?!?!?!?!?! Quite the opposite. I don't like to use global vars, so I strongly recommend it. Furthermore, you code didn't check if the match succeeded before using `$1`, so it could contain garbage. If you wanted to avoid using the return value, you'd have to use `my $x = $a =~ /(\d+)/ ? $1 : undef;` instead of `my ($x) = $a =~ /(\d+)/;`. But that's silly.

Answer (score 4):

Because regex tests are commonly used in boolean context, the scalar context return is always success or failure, not a captured value, and only list context will give you captured values. If it always returned a captured value, a captured '0' would look like failure in a boolean test.

As far as I am concerned, it is absolutely recommended to use the return value whenever possible; but to do so, you must use list context, such as a list assignment.

Answer (score 1):

In list mode, `=~` returns a list of matches. If your `$a` was `abc123def456ghi`, the first expression would return `(123, 456)`. You assign the first of these matches to `$x`.

In scalar mode, the `=~` operator returns the number of matches found, which is 1 in your case.

To extract values, don't use the return value of the regex operator, instead, use the `$&` and `$1` .. `$9` variables.

Comment: there's no /g flag, so it isn't going to try to match more than once